# Waiting for button press in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt4, signals-slots

I have a custom class inheriting from `QDialog`. I'm creating this dialog with function `foo`, and `foo` would like to continue doing its thing only when a certain button in the dialog is pressed. I was thinking of using signals and slots, but then how could I get `foo` to respond to a signal from another thread?

EDIT: basically I want to know how to reimplement the functionality of QInputDialog::getText() using my own dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your foo() function could call wait() on a [QWaitCondition][1] object, then your button could call wakeOne() on the same object to cause the wait() to return.

That said, there is really no necessity for using multithreading to reimplement QInputDialog::getText().  You should be able to reimplement that functionality inside a single thread without any problems, and doing it that way will be much simpler and more reliable.

(Note:  assuming you want your version of getText() to block and not return until after a button is pressed, you'll need to call QDialog::exec().  I don't recommend that style of programming though, as it's error-prone... for example, what happens if the user closes your QInputDialog's parent window while the QInputDialog is still open?  That deletes the QInputDialog object whose getText() method the program is still blocked inside, likely causing a crash because the QInputDialog's "this" pointer is now a dangling pointer.  It's much cleaner and safer to make everything event-based instead (i.e. signals and slots only), and not attempt to block or recurse Qt's event loop in your own code)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jeremy! Could you elaborate further on how I could go about using a single thread to implement `QInputDialog::getText()`? It seems I would have to get the main thread to wait for user input while the GUI obtains it. That is what I'm trying to do right now, but can't quite accomplish. What should I put into the `run()` function of the object that would enable it to create a dialog and then wait for the button press? I originally had an infinite loop checking if the button was pressed, but that only resulted in freezing the program.

Comment: Have a look at how QInputDialog::getText() is implemented in the Qt source code... looks like it creates a QInputDialog, then calls exec() on the dialog.  That's probably the easiest thing for you to do also.

Answer (score 1):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#modal-dialogs

Modal dialogs will block the user from interacting with other windows, which it sounds like you will need. Also, I think you want to call exec() instead of show(). Show() returns execution to the caller immediately, where as exec() blocks.